# I want to know the size of the Items in a ListView

Tags: listview, hidden

I want to know the size of the Items in a ListView. I can do it but first I need to show the ListView to the screen in hidden mode, Tell me syntax please.

My syntax (short) but not hidden mode...

```
ListView rssListView = null;
ArrayList<RssItem> rssItems = new ArrayList<RssItem>();
aa = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(this, R.layout.list_item, rssItems);
rssListView.setAdapter(aa);
```

Comment: the number of items in ListView or the ArrayList?

Comment: in ListView, I want to know the height of the Item, now getHeight() = 0

Comment: Can you edit your question including what you want to do exactly as it's rather ambiguous, do you want show the ListView to the screen in hidden mode or know the height of the Item or BOTH?

Comment: first android should draw a ListView, I can not measure the Items if it is not on the screen of

Comment: Give the option of not having to hide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following

```
rssListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```